# Output data from one Vue.js instance into another

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a pretty big page with lots of stuff going on. So i have 2 Vue instances for 2 parts of the page. How can i bind data from one Vue instance into another?

This example should show what i am trying to do. (it's not working that way)

```
<div class="app1">...</div>
...
<div class="app2">{{app1.$data.msg}}</div>
```

---

```
var app1 = new Vue({
    el: '.app1',
    data: {msg: "test"}
});

var app2 = new Vue({
    el: '.app2'
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In advance, I know this isn't the question you are asking, but I don't know why you need two instances of Vue. Why not just bind Vue to the `body` and treat both the Vue instances as components. It might be difficult to do what you are trying to do, because it was not intended. Maybe it was, I don't know. I have set Vue up on the body and I haven't seen a performance hit. Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vozuqetuqa/edit?html,js,output).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="app1">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="msg" class="form-control"/>

    </div>
    <div id="app2">
        <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
        <input type="text" v-model="msg" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var VueComponent1 = Vue.extend({
    template: '#app1',
    data: function(){
        return {
            msg: ""
        }
    }
});

var VueComponent2 = Vue.extend({
    template: '#app2',
    data: function(){
        return {
            msg: ""
        }
    }
});

var app1 = Vue.component('app1', VueComponent1);
var app2 = Vue.component('app2', VueComponent2);
var app = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: { msg: 'Everybody loves Vue.' }
});
```

If you are looking for a better way to separate you code, you might want to check out this [Vue with Browserify example](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-browserify-example).

[Laracasts has a free series](https://laracasts.com/series/learning-vuejs) on Vue which has been pretty informative as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am still looking for the best solution. The following feels a bit hacky but it works.

You can use the [watch option](http://vuejs.org/api/options#watch) to listen for the change of an expression and trigger a function. In this function you can update the desired data of another Vue instance. In you example we would do this:

```
var app1 = new Vue({
  el: '.app1',
  data: {msg: 'test'},
  watch: {
    'msg': function() { app2.msg = this.msg; }
  }
});

var app2 = new Vue({
  el: '.app2',
  data: { msg: app1.$data.msg },
  watch: {
    'msg': function() { app1.msg = this.msg; }
  }
});
```

You can see this at work in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/vayevubucu/1/edit?html,js,output).

Moreover, I am wondering if you even need to do this. If this was a real-life-situation there could be better ways to handle this avoiding this hacky solution.